# Building GDAL With Read/Write Support of FileGDB

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase

Has anyone been successful in building gdal with read/write support of file geodatabases?  I am able to build successfully, just never see FileGDB as in the supported vector formats.  Here is what I am doing:

1. Download latest gdal trunk (example: gdalsvn-trunk-20110822.zip)
2. Open the makegdal10.sln file in Visual Studio 2010
3. Edit the nmake.opt file, the ONLY thing I modify at this point is the GDAL_HOME variable, the FGDB section is still commented out.  Everything else left as is.
4. Build Solution 
   ------>SUCCESS
5. Uncomment the FGDB Section and set path to FGDB SDK
6. Open Visual Studio command line tools and cd to /ogr/ogrsf_frmts/filegdb
7. Execute nmake /f makefile.vc plugin
   ------>SUCCESS - I now have ogr_FileGDB.dll in that folder

Now, I copy the ogr_FileGDB.dll and the FileGDBAPI.dll to the bin folder containing ogr2ogr.exe.  When I run ogr2ogr --formats, I never get FileGDB as a format.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: From your description you didn't rebuild ogr2ogr with filegdb enabled. You just built the filegdb library. The two aren't linked based on the steps you describe.

Comment: You might also try the gdal-dev mailing list: http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev

Comment: I think @Sean's comment is really an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the GDAL_DRIVER_PATH environnement variable to point to the path where you put ogr_FileGDB.dll. Make sure also that the filegdb sdk DLLs are accessible in the PATH or put them next to ogr_FileGDB.dll. I've updated http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB to be more explicit about that